# Apple keyboard - swap alt and super keys

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, apple

I'd like to use my Apple wired keyboard with Elementary OS, so I want to swap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> keys. I've tried the changes that work for Ubuntu but they have no effect. Can anyone advise?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> System setting. Then in system setting go to to keyboard. This is where you change your shortcuts
>
> > Go to custom to make your own shortcuts

If my explanation are terrible just check the image below :)

[image]